# Does $0$ count as positive or negative root in Descartes' Sign Rule?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Consider the polynomial equation $f(x)= x^4-x^2=0$. The equation is ordered by descending variable exponent. Now to find out the number of positive and negative roots of this equation if I use [Descartes' Sign Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) and create the sequence of polynomial coefficients I get $$1 -1$$ where the number of sign changes between consecutive (nonzero) coefficients is $1$. It means that the number of positive roots `(*maximum* is omitted for $0$ and $1$)` is $1$ for this equation. However using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+-+x%5E2+%3D0) I get the roots are $x=-1, 0, 0, 1$.

Following Descartes' rule I get the number of negative roots of $f(x) =0$ are also $1$ since $f(x)=f(-x)$ which is good. Using the formula for complex roots $n- (p+q)$ if I take number of positive roots to be $p=1$ and negative roots to be $q=1$, I get $4-(1+1) =2$ which clearly is false.

So what is the mistake here? Does $0$ count as positive here?

Comment: Zeros are ignored in Descartes's sign rule.

Comment: @peter why is so?

Comment: Where did you get this "formula for complex roots"? I see no way for it to be correct unless you already know that there are no zero roots.

Comment: @IJMukta So in your comment you are asking for a proof of Descartes sign rule? That would be a long answer for anyone to post here, and useless since one can find a proof by searching the web [start with "Descartes rule of signs"].

Comment: @DavidK, [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs#Nonreal_roots).

Comment: Descartes's sing rule only cosiders positive real roots, nothing else. It does not state anything about non-positive or even non-real roots.

Comment: @NazmulHasanShipon Where this formula is given on Wikipedia, it first says, "if $f(x)$ is a polynomial which does not have a root at $0$". The equation $x^4-x^2=0$ has roots at $0,$ so the $n-(p+q)$ formula **is not correct** for this case (and Wikipedia never said it was).

Comment: You don't need a sign rule to tell you whether $0$ is a root. You just look at the non-zero term with the smallest power of $x.$ In this case that term is $-x^2,$ which tells you that $0$ is a root with multiplicity $2.$